# JS better to bind objects or make repeated global calls?

Tags: javascript, oop, optimization

I have a global object that most of my functions make calls to. Would there be any difference in efficiency if I bound the object to the function being called?

I suspect it will be slightly better, since every function seems to have a 'this' anyways, and global calls are supposed to be inefficient. So why not change the local 'this' (which isn't being used) to a global object that is being used. I'd be interested to see if anyone can answer this.

Ex. Original:

```
var obj = new Person();
Speak();

function Speak(){
    alert(obj.name);
}
```

Vs.

```
var obj = new Person();
obj.Speak();

obj.prototype.Speak = function(){
    alert(this.name);
};
```

Note: I simplified my example to draw attention away from it. I was worried it was taking more attention as a specific case rather than a question that was intended to be more academic.

Comment: Why aren't you putting the `Speak` function on your Person object? ie, `Person.prototype.Speak = function() ... obj.Speak()`

Comment: Perhaps it will be added to another object that holds a group of people later (ex. function Community()).

Or, in a more complicated but real case, the 'speak' function is passed as an argument and couldn't retain its object, so having it as a prototype seemed to offer no benefits. I just wanted to make this example simple, thank-you for pointing it out though.

Comment: I just realized how bad my second case is, another reason why it's good to point out these things. Anyways, for now just pretend it's necessary ;)

Comment: I suspect you wanted to do either `Speak.call(obj)` or `Speak.bind(obj)()`?

Comment: Your example is not very good. Try to explain what do you need it for. What the logic should be there. I assume something like this maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/74qfggfg/

Comment: Here is the real case: I have a page that navigates through hierarchical data. At any time is displays data from only one level of the hierarchy. I keep track of the current level and the current path via a javascript object. Since so many of my functions make calls to this object, I was wondering if it would be slightly more efficient if I used 'bind' to make the object local to each function rather than call it globally. It is more complicated to explain why I do not use prototypes, but the short answer is that it offers no benefits in my case (if this is the confusion, the answer is long)

Comment: I would prefer to keep this very simple, the purpose of the example was only to show what I meant about binding the object to make it local vs a global call. Let me know if you think my question does not have enough information in an area

Comment: Bind only applies to prototype function, I understand the comments now, sorry